# Select next row in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I've searched everywhere but can't seem to find a proper answer to this. Maybe I'm not using the right terms or something? Or maybe there is no answer...

So as an example, if you select the cell A1 and press enter, it moves the selection to B1. What I want to do is have row 1 highlighted, and then move the selection to row 2. I don't want to move the data from row 1 to row 2, I just want to change what I have selected/highlighted.

Is there some sort of key combination that does this? The best I can find so far would be to press the down key, and then shift + spacebar to select the row, but at that point I might as well just click every row like I was already doing.

Edit: Thanks for the downvote it really helps!

Answer (score 1):

Place this tiny macro in a standard module:

```
Sub MoveSelectionDownOneRow()
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

Then assign a shortcut key to it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with macros, you can just use the `DownArrow, Shift + Space` keyboard shortcut combo. `DownArrow` moves selection to the next row, `Shift + Space` selects the entire row.

Answer (score -1):

*I would like to suggest you MACRO(VBA) which enhances the scope of the Cursor movements, using this you can jump to any Row or Column*

Copy and Paste this as standard module.

```
Sub JumpToRowORColumn()

Dim sResult As String
On Error Resume Next

sResult = InputBox("Enter Row number or Column letter and press Ok.", "Jump To...")

  If IsNumeric(sResult) Then
      Cells(sResult, ActiveCell.Column).Select
    Else
      Cells(ActiveCell.Row, sResult).Select
  End If

End Sub
```

[image]

**How it Works:**

- Run the Macro.
- Write either Row number or Column name of your choice in the INPUT
  BOX
- Finish with Ok.

Comment: This has been unnecessarily down voted, since I've already mentioned that it has broader scope and it's not only jumps to next row but to any row & column. Other than  OP many should be benefited by this !!